# how show or hide an input window according to the input of a drop down list

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications

I am trying to set up a web page that takes in information of a course as input. I have a drop-down list that asks users to specify if the course has a weekly quiz. If the user selects "Yes", I want to display a few other input windows for the user to type in more details. on the contrary, if the user selects "No", nothing shows up.  I
am thinking to use c:if to achieve this goal, but I don't know how to actually do that. I tried a few times but it didn't work. I am new to the web-app development. What are the typial ways to do that?

My current JSP  looks like this.

```
<tr>
<td>Weekly Quiz</td>
<td>
<select name="quiz" id="quiz">
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
</td>
<c:if test="${param.quiz == 'Yes'}">
<input type="text" name="quizDetail" />
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi ,can you use javascript or jquery to achieve above.